# Does Glassfish 4.x require JDK 7 specifically?

Tags: java, glassfish

I was thinking about setting up a Java EE 7 framework to run Spring applications on Glassfish, which depends on JDK 7. However, we already have JDKs compatible with the newer specifications of Java 8 and Java 9. Would anyone happen to know whether Glassfish 4.x can run on these newer Java servers, or whether the current implementation of Glassfish uses any since-deprecated APIs from Java 7? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the Open Source Edition and not the [Enterprise](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html#ogsTab) one (which is 3.x as of now).

If that is the case, on the [Glassfish download page](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html#gfoseTab) the requirements listed are as follows:

> Java EE 7 requires JDK 7 or above, **JDK 8 u60 or above** is recommended for GlassFish 4.1.1.

So you can safely use JDK 7 or 8.

You may try JDK 9 as well, but it's not supported, [since it has not been released yet](http://www.java9countdown.xyz/).

Comment: For the benefit of others...GlassFish will not (currently) work on JDK 9 due to Sun making use of a lot of internal classes which are inaccessible in JDK 9 thanks to Jigsaw.

Comment: What about OpenJDK versus Oracle JDK?  not to hijack, but a compatability table...